# How to execute command on different router models

Tags: go, ssh

My task is execute command on different routers.

I'm using **golang.org/x/crypto/ssh** package

Cisco works fine.
But on HP output ends on prompt right before actual command

```
cmd := "dis int brief"
config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
   User: user,
   Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
      ssh.Password(password),
   },
   ...
}
...
conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", hostip+":22", config)
session, err := conn.NewSession()
output, err := session.CombinedOutput(cmd)
```

Here in output I'm getting only text before actual command, like command was never executed, but I'm not getting any errors too.

Is someone knows whats the problem with HP?

Comment: Can you clarify: a) specific model of HP router, b) `ssh` is working fine from command line ?

Comment: a) for example, MSR930 b) yes, ssh connection works fine from command line. as I said, seems like command executes successfully on router, but I just dont receive its output for some reason